# Samba and router DNS setup with custom DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, samba, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to use samba on ubuntu 16.04 as an AD DC. I use custom DNS servers (OpenDNS). How should I set the DNS settings up? (e.g. my router's address is 192.168.1.1, the server is 192.168.1.2). Should I put the server as DNS server on the router? Where can I put the custom nameservers' addresses?

Comment: You can set OpenDNS in your router or in /etc/resolv.conf Not is clear what relation have samba and openDNS here, but If you want OpenDNS in your server the best way is set it in /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

Your main source for Samba documentation should always be the [samba.org wiki.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Main_Page)  The main article there about using Samba as a DC is ["Setting up Samba as an Active Directory Domain Controller,"](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller) which says:

> AD DCs and domain members must use an DNS server that is able to resolve the AD DNS zones.

The only DNS backends that Samba supports are the one that's built-in to Samba or it can use an existing BIND backend with the BIND_DLZ plugin.  There's no indication that Samba can use an existing OpenDNS server.

If you follow the recommendation from Samba.org and make your AD domain a subdomain of a valid domain you already own (e.g. ad.yourdomain.com), then you can make your Samba AD the authority for that sub-domain and continue to use your OpenDNS server for the rest of your yourdomain.com names.